# Good resources to teach Natural Language Processing

Tags: undergraduate

What could be good resources to teach Natural language Processing to Undergraduate students?

I am using python as medium.

Comment: Nltk was the thing. Nowadays there seem to be more https://www.activestate.com/blog/natural-language-processing-nltk-vs-spacy/

Comment: Hi @Rusi... I came across 'spacy' by explosion. It is very cool and open source... I am looking further to explore

Comment: Er... I don't get what you mean: "explosion" ?!

Comment: Check this out https://spacy.io/

Comment: explosion is the company which created spacy